# SQL Date Format with T between Date and Time

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

I have an output that shows a timestamp field as something like "2020-06-29T23:58:34.000Z". How can I properly format it to something like "2020-06-29 23:55:34"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(timestamp_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: but can I keep it as date+time format? Using to_char will change the field type , right?

Comment: So I tried to_timestamp(to_char(a.update_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), but I got "java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Comment: @user12562215 . . . Huh?  You want to leave it as a string if you care about the format.